# Adding sound to page using jquery

Tags: jquery, jplayer

What is the preferred method to add sound to a page using jquery?

I am considering using jPlayer but have my doubts about it. Depending on the messages being displayed on the screen, I need to customize the sound.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add sound? I hope you're creating some kind of game.

Comment: I wish. It's an alert system for our group :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I find random audio on a website really annoying but here you go:

```
<audio>
        <source src="audio/audio.mp3"></source>
        <source src="audio/audio.ogg"></source>
        HTML5 Needed
</audio>

<script>
    var audio = $("audio")[0];
    audio.play();
</script>
```

or something like:

```
$("<audio></audio>").attr({
    'src':'audio/something.mp3',
    'volume':0.4,
    'autoplay':'autoplay'
}).appendTo("body");
```

Both these examples use HTML5 but with small modifications you can use flash to play the audio.

Comment: Thanks. This is not going to be a public website. The sound is being added to wake up sleeping dispatchers.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it solves the problem?

Comment: We aren't using HTML5 yet so I can't use the audio tag.

Comment: You can use the object tag and a flash player with the 2nd example. Most newer browsers support html5 anyway. http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Comment: Thanks Meisam. That link you sent me lead to happyworm, who are the makers of jPlayer, so I just stuck to using jPlayer. Did accept your vote though.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i prefer jPlayer and use it heavily. But you could consider Soundmanager, too. 
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/